# Solution for Manual index for EE1.13

Tags: reindex, enterprise-1.13

I have a client that would like the option of manually indexing the tables that are no longer indexable from the admin section.

We have created a cron that runs every 4 hours but the client would also like the ability to do this at will.

[image]

Has anyone made an extension to override this and allow the functionality for the rest?

Answer (score 1):

magerun can index these. You could probably snipe the code from there and easily create an admin controller to do this.

Anyhow, whenever I need to index those I trigger from magerun.

Comment: It is a client asking for access to those values. We ended up creating a custom ext to do this.